# OverGrive not work after restart computer

Tags: google, google-drive

I successfully installed OverGrive (https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive) on Ubuntu 15.04, which made the connection and sync without major problems, but after restarting the computer the software does not connect to google account and show me the setup window again.

After close the setup window I can not reopen it.

I saw that the OverGrive continues running in the backend, after killing the process and restart it by terminal I have the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overgrive.py", line 1414, in on_account_button
  File "overgrive.py", line 3716, in get_authorization_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2217, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    cache=cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError('File not found: "%s"' % filename)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: File not found: "client_secrets.json"
```

Anyone have any idea how I can try to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [installation instructions](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu) online :

NOTE : It is important to allow overGrive to finish the first sync completely. If the first sync does not complete it will open the overGrive setup screen again on restart. You can simply select Start Sync again to complete the synchronization process.